# How to identify distinct values in a column based on duplicates in another column

Tags: sql-server

I got three columns in a table:

```
  Name  Ascii_Name  Alternate_names

  Abat     Abat1       Abat, Abat1
  Abayah   Abayah1     Abayah,Abayah1
  Abayah   Abayah1     Abayah,Abayah1
  Abat     Abat1       Abat, Abath
  Carne    Carnt       Carne, Carnt
```

For the (Name and Ascii_Name) pair where the values are same I have to find the values in Alternate_names where the values are distinct. The result set has to contain Alternate_Names where the (Name and Ascii_Name) pair are repeating at least twice. The result has to be as follows:

```
 Name   Ascii_Name  Alternate_names
  Abat     Abat1       Abat, Abat1
  Abat     Abat1       Abat, Abath
```

Kindly note the result set doesn't contain the last row value ( Carne    Carnt       Carne, Carnt) since it did not get repeated.

Comment: don't quite understand your logic here. Can you explain further ?

Comment: @Squirrel Added more information in the description for clarity.

Comment: so the query that i posted does it gives you what you wanted ?

Answer (score 1):

By looking at your result set gained from the original table, I think you want to find the Name & Ascii_Name are same and but different Alternate Name. Please find the below query..

```
DECLARE @Collection TABLE(

    Name            VARCHAR(MAX),
    Ascii_Name      VARCHAR(MAX),
    Alternate_names VARCHAR(MAX)

)

---- Tempory table data insert
INSERT INTO @Collection VALUES  ('Abat','Abat1','Abat, Abat1'),
                                ('Abayah','Abayah1','Abayah,Abayah1'),
                                ('Abayah','Abayah1','Abayah,Abayah1'),
                                ('Abat','Abat1','Abat, Abath')

-- Solution
SELECT  col1.Name,
        col1.Ascii_Name,
        col1.Alternate_names 
FROM @Collection col1
INNER JOIN @Collection col2 ON col1.Name = col1.Name AND col1.Ascii_Name = col2.Ascii_Name 
WHERE col1.Alternate_names <> col2.Alternate_names
```

[Try It](http://rextester.com/CSFC1401)

Comment: The result set has to contain Alternate_Names where the (Name and Ascii_Name) pair are repeating at least twice.

Comment: @SreedharDanturthi - as your result set in your question result set will repeat 2 or more according to the alternate_name, please try it http://rextester.com/CSFC1401

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want ?

```
select Name, Ascii_Name
from   yourtable
group by Name, Ascii_Name
having min(Alternate_names) <> max(Alternate_names)
```

Comment: Added more information in the question for clarity.